# Can two different continuous forms run off the same queryi in access 2010?

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba, ms-access-2010

So I have two subforms, one to show internal training course completion for an employee and the other is the same thing but for vendor training.

Both subforms pull the same data from the same table, but display different selective data (different columns from the table).

I added the employee search combobox code to reflect the second "vendor training" subform:

```
Private Sub cboEmployee_AfterUpdate()
    On Error GoTo Proc_Error
    If IsNull(Me.cboEmployee) Then
        Me.subEmployeeCourseTrainingCompletion.Form.Filter = ""
        Me.subEmployeeCourseTrainingCompletion.Form.FilterOn = False
        Me.subEmployeeVendorCourseTrainingCompletion.Form.Filter = ""
        Me.subEmployeeVendorCourseTrainingCompletion.Form.FilterOn = False
    Else
        Me.subEmployeeCourseTrainingCompletion.Form.Filter = "[EmployeeID]=" & Me.cboEmployee
        Me.subEmployeeCourseTrainingCompletion.Form.FilterOn = True
        Debug.Print Me.subEmployeeCourseTrainingCompletion.Form.Filter
        Me.subEmployeeVendorCourseTrainingCompletion.Form.Filter = "[EmployeeID]=" & Me.cboEmployee
        Me.subEmployeeVendorCourseTrainingCompletion.Form.FilterOn = True
        Debug.Print Me.subEmployeeVendorCourseTrainingCompletion.Form.Filter
    End If
Proc_Exit:
        Exit Sub
Proc_Error:
        MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " in setting subEmployeeCourseTrainingCompletion filter:" & vbCrLf & Err.Description
        MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " in setting subEmployeeVendorCourseTrainingCompletion filter:" & vbCrLf & Err.Description
        Resume Proc_Exit
End Sub
```

The internval training subform still works and updates based on the employee ID in the combobox, but the second, vendor, subform doesn't update.

Any ideas as to why and possible solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Force the update of the second form once you have made changes and saved the data in the first one:

```
Me.subEmployeeVendorCourseTrainingCompletion.Form.Requery
```

You could do this in the `Form_AfterUpdate` of the first subform:

```
Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
    Parent.subEmployeeVendorCourseTrainingCompletion.Form.Requery
End Sub
```

---

**UPDATE**

Try another approach. Instead of setting filters use the `Link Child Fields` and `Link Master Fields` properties of the subforms in order to link the subforms to the main form.

Comment: I just tried this. It's not updating the second form. Any other ideas?